# subset with complete panels in data frame based on column entry

Tags: subset

I would like to create two subsets of my data frame called "data". The original data frame contains three panels/groups: Afghanistan, Brazil and Germany with entries for three years 1999-2001.

Subset ONE should contain only countries where population > 500,000 in year 1999. This means that not only a particular row where population was <=500,000 in year 1999 is removed, but the whole panel/group/country.

Subset TWO should contain only panels/groups/countries where the mean of population over the three years is >500,000. I think this would mean that one would first create a new variable of "data$meanpop" and then create the subset.

I have tried playing around with subset and dplyr packages/functions, but I cannot get it to work.

A minimal example:

```
a <- c(rep("Afghanistan",3),
   rep("Brazil",3),
   rep("Germany",3))
b <- c(1999:2001,1999:2001,1999:2001)
c <- c(520000,510000,530000,20,0,5,NA,7000,1800000)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
colnames(data) <- c("country","year","population")

data
country year population
1 Afghanistan 1999     520000
2 Afghanistan 2000     510000
3 Afghanistan 2001     530000
4      Brazil 1999         20
5      Brazil 2000          0
6      Brazil 2001          5
7     Germany 1999       <NA>
8     Germany 2000       7000
9     Germany 2001    1800000
```

Resulting subset ONE should look like this:

```
1 Afghanistan 1999     520000
2 Afghanistan 2000     510000
3 Afghanistan 2001     530000
```

Resulting subset TWO should look like this (I did not create a data$average column here):

```
country year population   meanpop
1 Afghanistan 1999     520000 520000.00
2 Afghanistan 2000     510000 520000.00
3 Afghanistan 2001     530000 520000.00
7     Germany 1999       <NA> 903500.00
8     Germany 2000       7000 903500.00
9     Germany 2001    1800000 903500.00
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my questions for those who come across similar issues.

Subset ONE:

```
newdata <- data[ which(data$year==1999 & data$population>500000),]
keep <- newdata$country
data[data$country==keep,]
```

gives you:

```
# country year population
# 1 Afghanistan 1999     520000
# 2 Afghanistan 2000     510000
# 3 Afghanistan 2001     530000
```

Subset TWO:

```
a <- by(data$population,data$country,mean,na.rm=T)
a
a > 500000 #to check countries by 'eye'

means <- as.data.frame(a[data$country])
colnames(means) <- "popmean"
means <- round(means,2)
data2 <- cbind(data,means) #now we have a new variable with the panel means
newdata2 <- data2[ which(data2$popmean>500000),]
```

Gives you:

```
#               country year population popmean
# 1 Afghanistan 1999     520000  520000
# 2 Afghanistan 2000     510000  520000
# 3 Afghanistan 2001     530000  520000
# 7     Germany 1999         NA  903500
# 8     Germany 2000       7000  903500
# 9     Germany 2001    1800000  903500
```

If anyone knows a simpler way to solve this I'd still appreciate your comments so that I can improve my coding skills.